# return value from async Firestore query swift

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, completionhandler

I am trying to query my Firestore database to see if a desired username is taken. The query works, however I need to return a value if it is empty or not to see if the username already exists. I am trying to use a completion handler but it doesn't seem to work:

```
 func checkUserTaken(cleanUsername: String ,completion:@escaping(String) -> (Void)){
    
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    var userTaken: String = ""
   

    let docRef = db.collection("users").whereField("username", isEqualTo: cleanUsername)
    docRef.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        
        
    } else {
        if(querySnapshot!.documents.isEmpty){
            print("user is available")
            userTaken = "user is available"
        }
        else{
            print("user is taken")
            userTaken = "user is taken"
        }
        
        }
      
        completion(userTaken)
    }
```

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" mean? Does it not reach the completion handler? Is there an error getting the documents?

Comment: @jnpdx it the completion handler doesn't return the value/ it doesn't reach the completion handler

Comment: I am basically trying to use the completion handler as a return statement... Does it return values the same way? I am pretty new to swift programming. @jnpdx

Comment: Which print statement does it reach? A completion handler is not the same as a return statement. Maybe you could show where you are calling checkUserToken

Comment: `checkUserTaken(cleanUsername: cleanedUsername){ res in
             return(res)
        }` @jnpdx this is how I am calling it and yes it does reach all the print statements correctly based on if the user is taken or not

Comment: Add that in your question with some context about what you're expecting to happen (aka what you want to do with `res`). You're correct that doing `return(res)` won't do anything.

Comment: I am trying to return the string value in the completion handler by calling it as such. Is that correct? @jnpdx

Comment: You can't `return` from within a closure to an outside scope like that. Once again, add that to your question with some context about how you're actually trying to use `res` (not just that you're "trying to return" it) and perhaps I or someone else can help.

Comment: The inherent issue with doing this is that to check to see if the username is available, the app has to be able read the `users` node. That means either A) The user doing the check must have already authenticated/created a Firebase account or B) The users node is wide open to reading by anyone e.g. There are no read rules (read: true in the rules). Just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

This task is a good way to learn some important and helpful things about Swift, such as naming conventions, deciding what to return from functions (you chose a string, I opted for a boolean), accounting for errors, etc.

```
func checkUsername(_ username: String, completion: @escaping (_ taken: Bool?) -> Void) {
    Firestore.firestore().collection("users").whereField("username", isEqualTo: username).getDocuments() { (snapshot, err) in
        if let snapshot = snapshot {
            if snapshot.documents.isEmpty {
                completion(false)
            } else {
                completion(true)
            }
        } else {
            if let err = err {
                print(err)
            }
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
checkUsername("drake") { (taken) in
    guard let taken = taken else {
        // handle error, maybe retry?
        return
    }
    if taken {
        // prompt user username is taken
    } else {
        // username not taken, proceed
    }
}
```

In the signature of the function, I labeled the boolean in the completion closure (`taken`), which the Swift compiler does not require you do but I think can be very helpful.

By the way, this function can return anything, even a `Result` object which is a neat way to return an object or an `Error` in a single object. But I think returning a boolean is straightforward enough here. I made the boolean an optional so the function can return three possible states (true, false, or nil) to give you a way to handle errors.

**String return**

```
func checkUsername(_ username: String, completion: @escaping (_ name: String?) -> Void) {
    Firestore.firestore().collection("users").whereField("username", isEqualTo: username).getDocuments() { (snapshot, err) in
        if let snapshot = snapshot {
            if snapshot.documents.isEmpty {
                completion(username) // return the username if it's available
            } else {
                completion("") // return an empty string if taken
            }
        } else {
            if let err = err {
                print(err)
            }
            completion(nil) // return nil if error
        }
    }
}

checkUsername("drake") { (name) in
    guard let name = name else {
        // handle error
        return
    }
    if name.isEmpty {
        // username taken
    } else {
        print(name) // username not taken
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way that I could return a string from the function call if the bool is true? @MJ-12

Comment: @RileyDrake of course, you can return or configure this function to do anything. You can return a string and a boolean together or a custom object that contains them both. But you can accomplish this task with just one object (a string or a boolean) and from it you can determine all possible outcomes (taken, available, error). I updated my answer to return a string, which returns the username itself if it's available, otherwise empty if it's taken and `nil` if there was an error.

Comment: `checkUsername(cleanedUsername) { (name) in
            guard let name = name else {
                // handle error
                return
            }
            
            if name.isEmpty {
                // username taken
                isTaken = true
                
            } else {
                print(name) // username not taken
                isTaken = false
                
            }
            print(isTaken)
            return
        }
        
        print(isTaken)`  @MJ-12

Comment: When I change the value of isTaken in the func call it does not save outside of the function. I believe this might have something to do with dispatch groups but I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: You would have to post that code for me to be able to help.